# Google Cloud Storage

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-api-java-client

I have recently started developing an app in Java using Google Cloud Platform services and I would like to use google cloud storage for image/video storage. 
After having researched thoroughly through google's own documentation and found out that there are several ways of using the Cloud Storage service I am a little confused..

From what i've read, the service can be accessed using the XML API or the JSON API . Assuming that i choose the JSON API this is divided also in two alternatives as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/libraries) .
Using, Google API Client Libraries or using Google Cloud Client Libraries so
my question is: **which approach is considered more up-to-date and more efficient in terms of code complexity??**

I do understand that probably it depends, but i would like to hear a view from people with "guru" status in the google cloud platform.

Thanks!

Comment: I totally understand the confusion part. Google keeps moving the documentation around and changing names of their libraries and packages. It gets a little easier once you write some code, but it remains confusing even for long-time Google Platform users. However, I would take "too many options" over a dead/forgotten library any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need core features and plan to run your app on App Engine, use [Cloud Storage Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#downloading_the_client_library). It's easier to use (as of the time of this answer) for most basic features.

If you plan to run your code outside of App Engine instances and/or need features that Google API Client Library does not support (e.g. resumable uploads), use [Google Cloud Java library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please elaborate a little bit on Google cloud java library? What other uses may benefit? If it helps the app I am building will have social features like image uploading,chat etc.

Comment: Unless your users upload huge files, I suggest that you start with App Engine client library. If, at some point, it won't be enough, you can always switch to GCloud library. All the concepts are the same (e.g. buckets, objects, ACLs, etc.), and most of the functionality is the same. So switching/mixing is easy. Plus, who knows how these libraries are going to change over the next months or years.

Answer (score 0):

A new option to add to the previous answer is the [NIO Filesystem Provider for Google Cloud Storage](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-contrib/google-cloud-nio). It provides native Java access to Google cloud storage so it's the easiest to use.